# How do I copy directory structure containing placeholders

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, rsync, placeholder

I have the situation, where a template directory - containing files and links (!) - needs to be copied recursively to a destination directory, preserving all attributes. The template directory contains any number of placeholders (`__NOTATION__`), that need to be renamed to certain values.

For example template looks like this:

```
./template/__PLACEHOLDER__/name/__PLACEHOLDER__/prog/prefix___FILENAME___blah.txt
```

Destination becomes like this:

```
./destination/project1/name/project1/prog/prefix_customer_blah.txt
```

What I tried so far is this:

```
# first create dest directory structure
while read line; do
  dest="$(echo "$line" | sed -e 's#__PLACEHOLDER__#project1#g' -e 's#__FILENAME__#customer#g' -e 's#template#destination#')"
  if ! [ -d "$dest" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$dest"
  fi
done < <(find ./template -type d)

# now copy files
while read line; do
  dest="$(echo "$line" | sed -e 's#__PLACEHOLDER__#project1#g' -e 's#__FILENAME__#customer#g' -e 's#template#destination#')"
  cp -a "$line" "$dest"
done < <(find ./template -type f)
```

However, I realized that if I want to take care about permissions and links, this is going to be endless and very complicated. Is there a better way to replace __PLACEHOLDER__ with "value", maybe using `cp`, `find` or `rsync`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your script will already do what you want, if only you replace

```
find ./template -type f
```

with

```
find ./template ! -type d
```

---

Otherwise, the obvious solution is to use `cp -a` to make an "archive" copy of the template, complete with all links, permissions, etc, and *then* rename the placeholders in the copy.

```
cp -a ./template ./destination
while read path; do
  dir=`dirname "$path"`
  file=`basename "$path"`
  mv -v "$path" "$dir/${file//__PLACEHOLDER__/project1}"
done < <(`find ./destination -depth -name '*__PLACEHOLDER__*'`)
```

Note that you'll want to use `-depth` or else renaming files inside renamed directories will break.

If it's very important to you that the directory tree is created with the names already changed (i.e. you must never see placeholders in the destination), then I'd recommend simply using an intermediate location.

Comment: I tought about this solution as well, which is in fact feasible for me. But I noticed that I would have to move the directories from "left to right". Because for example mv ./template/__PLACEHOLDER__/name/__PLACEHOLDER__/prog/prefix___FILENAME___blah.txt ./destination/project1/name/project1/prog/prefix_customer_blah.txt results in a "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: That's what the `-depth` thing is about.

Comment: That's true. Thank you! Will try and come back.

Answer (score 0):

First copy with rsync,  preserving all the properties and links etc.
Then change the placeholder strings in the destination filenames:

```
#!/bin/bash

TEMPL="$PWD/template" # somewhere else

DEST="$PWD/dest"      # wherever it is

mkdir "$DEST"
(cd "$TEMPL"; rsync -Hra . "$DEST")   # 
MyRen=$(mktemp)
trap "rm -f $MyRen" 0 1 2 3 13 15

cat >$MyRen <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
fn="$1"
newfn="$(echo "$fn" |  sed -e 's#__PLACEHOLDER__#project1#g' -e s#__FILENAME__#customer#g' -e 's#template#destination#')"
test "$fn" != "$newfn" &&  mv "$fn" "$newfn"
EOF

chmod +x $MyRen

find "$DEST" -depth -execdir $MyRen {} \;
```